# Makefile that updates the default target to the last one specified

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile which can compile a release build or a debugging build (i.e. with `-O3` or `-g` respectively. The first and default one is `release` so `make` is equivalent to `make release`. Sometimes I `make debug` but am so used to just typing `make` that the next time I compile it goes back to release.

Is there a way the makefile could remember the last target specified and default to that if no arguments are given?

This has a similar title, but is really a different question: [How does "make" app know default target to build if no target is specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057689/how-make-app-knows-default-target-to-build-if-no-target-is-specified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This writes the last target name into a file, `.default_make_target`, which is then used as the default target when no arguments are given. It shows the correct target name in the output and exits with `Nothing to be done for 'target'.` correctly when its out of date.

```
DEFAULT_TARGET=debug
LAST_TARGET_FILE=.default_make_target
LAST_TARGET=$(foreach f, $(wildcard $(LAST_TARGET_FILE)), $(shell cat $(f)))

.PHONY: debug release clean

.DEFAULT_GOAL:= $(or $(LAST_TARGET),$(DEFAULT_TARGET))

debug: CFLAG_OPTS+= -g
debug: CHOSEN_TARGET=debug
debug: real_target

release: CFLAG_OPTS+= -O3
release: CHOSEN_TARGET=release
release: real_target

real_target:
    @echo $(CHOSEN_TARGET) > $(LAST_TARGET_FILE)
    echo '$(CFLAG_OPTS)' > real_target #just an example

clean:
    rm -f real_target
```

Testing...

```
> make debug
echo '-g' > real_target
> make
make: Nothing to be done for 'debug'.
> make clean
rm -f real_target
> make release
echo '-O3' > real_target
> make
make: Nothing to be done for 'release'.
>
```

*UPDATED:

- Previously I had `@echo debug > $(LAST_TARGET_FILE)` as the body of the phony debug rule (and likewise for release), which meant `debug`/`release` were [always out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852535/makefile-dependencies-dont-work-for-phony-target). Instead, it needs to be run in the body of a real target, for which `CHOSEN_TARGET` is set.
- Rather than `default: $(if...)`, using [`.DEFAULT_GOAL:=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057689/how-make-app-knows-default-target-to-build-if-no-target-is-specified) now causes the correct target to be printed when up to date. For example `make: Nothing to be done for 'release'.`

Comment: Ugly as sin, but also just about the only way to do it.

Comment: You make like to use `or` make function `$(or $(LAST_TARGET),$(DEFAULT_TARGET))`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin thanks! getting into a whole world of hurt getting around [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852535/makefile-dependencies-dont-work-for-phony-target) issue that causes the above to always be out of date. Will fix and update soon.

Answer (score 1):

I like this a bit better:

```
LAST_TARGET_FILE=.last_target
UPDATE_LAST_TARGET=@echo "LAST_TARGET=$@" >$(LAST_TARGET_FILE)

-include $(LAST_TARGET_FILE)

.PHONY: default
default: $(firstword $(LAST_TARGET) release)

.PHONY: debug
debug:
    $(UPDATE_LAST_TARGET)
    echo debug

.PHONY: release
release:
    $(UPDATE_LAST_TARGET)
    echo release
```

Comment: Or just put the rule in the file directly, or put an assignment before the include to avoid the `firstword`, or ...